# Do...Loop starts too quickly, how to brake it?

Tags: vb.net

With my program, user have to download and save csv files to two different specific directories. Unfortunately automatic downloading not possible. To download file I use command WebBrowser1.Navigate(url), which run php script on the target web page and after one second webBrowser ask path where I or user want to download file. After that again button click and .Navigate to download second one. 
But I have to be sure, that user had download file exactly to the specific directory and first, I want to check if file exists there. And here problems are starts. Because of small delay before "Save" possibility, program run immediately Do...Loop process and "Save" window doesn't even come. Also I tried to use thread.sleep, but it doesn't help. Because it immediately go to sleep and "save" window have not time to present. After sleep it immediately starts Do...Loop process. 
Is here some other instruments to say to my program, that it wait a little and continue to run code after user "Save" file?
Here is My code:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            Dim kraporttila As String
            Dim dt1 As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
            Dim dt2 As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value
            Dim faa As String = dt1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Dim fla As String = dt2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")            
            Dim ddla As String = dt2.ToString("MM.yy")            
            Dim kuitti As Uri = New Uri("https:url/kuitti.php?faa=" & faa & "&fla=" & fla & "&fk_e=&fa_e=&fm=&ftil=&kuittiexportcsv=Lataa%CSV")            
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(kuitti)
            Button2.Visible = False
            Do While
                If System.IO.File.Exists(kraporttila) = True Then
                   Button3.Text = "Lataa maksuvirheet"
                   Button3.Visible = True
                   Label3.Text = "Nyt lataa maksuviheet ja tellenna kansioon ""C:\Users\Ivan\" & ddla & "\Laskutukset ja Maksuvirheet\Maksuvirheet"""
                   Exit Do
                Else
                   Continue Do
                End If
            Loop
        End Sub
```

Comment: Put you download code into webbrowser documentcompleted event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: You'll need a Timer.  Do talk to the web site owner, this is hard to make reliable.

Comment: Test the possibility to download the file using HttpClient, WebRequest or WebClient. If the file is generated on-demand only and transferred directly right after, then no luck. You could use [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) to be notified when a file has been created, at some point, in a specific path. When this all depends on a user's direct intervention, the whole procedure may become a little sketchy.

Comment: did you tried DoEvents?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help. It work exactly as Jimi said. But I went to an other way, just added one more botton "Continue" and this button check is the file exists.